# load js file after view composition in Durandal 2.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, durandal

Like the title says, I would like to load an external JS file after view composition.  I've been able to include my own jquery for DOM manipulation using the compositionComplete binding, but require.js seems to load all files before the composition html.  Is there a way?

Comment: is leveraging require a must? in the production case, you should be bundling your javascript, which would make this question irrelevant.

Comment: what is the use case for that?

Comment: I have a js file with some jquery in it which should modify the dom.  The problem is that require loads it with the shell.js once, and the functions in the file are not bound to composite views.  Now that I explain it, I think it might just be a scope issue rather than a require issue

Comment: Durandal uses knockout, ideally you would be utilising this and not  manipulating the dom with jquery, you would manipulate the viewmodel and allow knockout to represent this data for you. That said, could you not use `var myjqueryscript = require("yourscript")` within composition complete?

Comment: I agree that I should be using knockout, however I'm using some theme for now that requires the use of some Jquery which I'm lazy to rewrite in knockout.